# Pig UDF running on AWS EMR with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/LoadFunc

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I am developing an application that try to read log file stored in S3 bucks and parse it using Elastic MapReduce. Current the log file has following format

```
------------------------------- 
COLOR=Black 
Date=1349719200 
PID=23898 
Program=Java 
EOE 
------------------------------- 
COLOR=White 
Date=1349719234 
PID=23828 
Program=Python 
EOE
```

So I try to load the file into my Pig script, but the build-in Pig Loader doesn't seems be able to load my data, so I have to create my own UDF. Since I am pretty new to Pig and Hadoop, I want to try script that written by others before I write my own, just to get a teast of how UDF works. I found one from here http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html, there is a SimpleTextLoader. In order to compile this SimpleTextLoader, I have to add a few imports, as

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat; 
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit; 
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException; 
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple; 
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray; 
import org.apache.pig.PigException; 
import org.apache.pig.LoadFunc;
```

Then, I found out I need to compile this file. I have to download svn and pig running

```
sudo apt-get install subversion 
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk 
ant
```

Now i have a pig.jar file, then I try to compile this file.

```
javac -cp ./trunk/pig.jar SimpleTextLoader.java 
jar -cf SimpleTextLoader.jar SimpleTextLoader.class
```

It compiles successful, and i type in Pig entering grunt, in grunt i try to load the file, using

```
grunt> register file:/home/hadoop/myudfs.jar
grunt> raw = LOAD 's3://mys3bucket/samplelogs/applog.log' USING myudfs.SimpleTextLoader('=') AS (key:chararray, value:chararray); 

2012-12-05 00:08:26,737 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/pig/LoadFunc Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig_1354666051892.log
```

Inside the pig_1354666051892.log, it has

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/pig/LoadFunc

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/LoadFunc
```

I also try to use another UDF (UPPER.java) from http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual, and I am still get the same error by try to use UPPER method. Can you please help me out, what's the problem here? Much thanks!

UPDATE: I did try EMR build-in Pig.jar at /home/hadoop/lib/pig/pig.jar, and get the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in Pig support in EMR?

Comment: yeah, I did use the build-in pig at /home/hadoop/lib/pig/pig.jar but still get the same error. I also specifically registered this pig.jar file in my script. But still get the same error.

Comment: You can simply provide the Pig script that you developed locally to the EMR by putting it in S3. All the configuration and bootstrapping is taken care by AWS for you.

Comment: I am running in the interactive mode.

Comment: EMR is better to run in scale. I suggest you to develop your script in local mode on your machine and only deployed the final script to EMR. Anyway, note that you can have a several version of Hadoop in the EMR cluster. Maybe you didn't select the correct version that you wanted.

Comment: I am running Hadoop 1.0.3 (Amazon Distribution). Just wondering by looking at the process I am compile my UDF java file, do you find any mistake int he process I am compiling it? Inside the pig.jar, it did included a org.apache.pig.LoadFunc.class. The error reporting NoClassDefFoundError doesn't seems help me to find the problem. OR do you have any experience for writing UDF in pig that would share with me? I am pretty new to Pig UDF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20664/discussion-between-simon-guo-and-guy)

Answer (score 0):

Put the UDF jar in the /home/hadoop/lib/pig directory or copy the pig-*-amzn.jar file to /home/hadoop/lib and it will work.

You would probably use a bootstrap action to do either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Hadoop ecosystem tools like pig and hive look up $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh for environment variables.

I was able to resolve this issue by adding pig-0.13.0-h1.jar (it contains all the classes required by the UDF) to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/hadoop/pig-0.13.0/pig-0.13.0-h1.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

pig-0.13.0-h1.jar is available in the Pig home directory.