# Can't find Accumulator when using DataFu with AWS Pig v0.11

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to use [`datafu.pig.stats.StreamingQuantile`](http://linkedin.github.io/datafu/docs/javadoc/datafu/pig/stats/StreamingQuantile.html) in LinkedIn's great [DataFu](http://engineering.linkedin.com/open-source/introducing-datafu-open-source-collection-useful-apache-pig-udfs) library. However, I get the following error from Pig when it reaches the first `StreamingQuantile` usage:

```
2013-08-03 00:55:45,294 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/pig/Accumulator
```

In the logfile, I see the following:

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/pig/Accumulator

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/Accumulator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
(snip)
```

I've tried using `register` to include guava.jar and also pig.jar. Neither one helps. As a belt-and-suspenders approach, I tried including several jars from the lib:

```
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/guava-13.0.1.jar
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/pig-0.11.1.1-amzn.jar
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/pig.jar
register s3://my-s3-location/datafu-0.0.10.jar
register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
```

This doesn't seem to be common. I mean, obviously NoClassDefFoundError is common, but not Accumulator, especially with DataFu. [Here's the closest question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402206/cdh4-hbase-using-pig-error-2998-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoo) but it's related to hbase and I couldn't find anything that helped out. [The only answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714800/pig-udf-running-on-aws-emr-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-pig-l) also indicates something I tried, unfortunately.

Comment: What happens if you register all of the jars? EG `register file:/home/hadoop/lib/*.jar` and `register file:/home/hadoop/lib/pig/*.jar`.

Comment: that was a great idea, but it didn't work, error 2998 again.

Comment: Did you finally find your answer? I had somehow similar issues.

Comment: @natdico no, didn't find an answer, and I just abandoned the effort. If you find something, post the answer and I'll accept.